# Investigate to /proc/loadavg

Tags: linux

Review linux load average documentation (to try to solve a problem) I'm ask if a kind of state of process (zombie process?) can affect to anomaly that causes an high load average of my system. So, zombie processes can have negative effects to my problem? Are there other kind of state of process that increase load average?

Comment: Correct my if it wrong, normally an high load avarage come from: CPU, consuming ram --> goes to swap, I/O disks. I'm not sure about sockets and/or network (excluding possible DDOS attacks or similar)

Answer (score 3):

Only processes that are in the state of uninterruptible sleep or running count to load average. All other states do not contribute to the load average.

So, no, zombies do not contribute to load. They do nothing but pollute the process table and consume some kernel memory in doing so.